# Is it possible to use Spring API Gateway for threat protection?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm going to implement API Gateway using Netflix Zuul. Is it possible to setup any rules for protection against:

- SQL Injection,
- XML Threat Protection
- JSON Threat Protection

I found only external solution (API Gateways) supporting it :(