# Is it possible to use Spring Cloud Gateway for threat protection?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm going to implement API Gateway using Spring Cloud Gateway (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/). Is it possible to setup any rules for protection against:

SQL Injection,
XML Threat Protection
JSON Threat Protection
I found only external solution (API Gateways) supporting it :(

Previously I was looking for Netflix Zull solution ([Is it possible to use Spring API Gateway for threat protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422198/is-it-possible-to-use-spring-api-gateway-for-threat-protection)), but I switched to Spring Cloud Gateway.

Comment: Only way I know of flagging SQL injection in API Gateway is to parse the request body and check for patterns which look similar to injection. If my assumption is correct (and possible), you'll have to run that check on every request. Even if only one of the back-end service uses a DB. Very inefficient.

Comment: I have used Zuul and not SCG (but both are pretty similar). In Zuul, it is possible to define a **Filter** to parse request body and run checks/operations on it. So, yes, if you know the rules it is *possible* to setup rules for protection against threats you mentioned.

Comment: @narendra-choudhary do you mean write it from scratch? btw. I know this is inefficient, but I have to fulfil customer requirement...